# RXJS Catch operator not catch the Error

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, webstorm, ngrx

I have an issue when I try to set up redux in my Angular4 project, I use the code following to manage the login actions:

```
@Effect()
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.act
    .ofType(actions.LOGIN)
    .map((action: actions.LoginAction) => action.payload)
    .switchMap((val: { email: string, password: string }) => this.authService.login(val.email, val.password)
      .map(auth => new actions.LoginSuccessAction(auth))
      .catch(err =>  of(new actions.LoginFailAction(err))));
```

[image]

*For some reason Webstorm didn't recognize the rxjs "map" operator but it works well when compile.*

And Inside the authService I defined the mock log in check:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    if (email == 'a@gmail.com') {
      return Observable.of('Login Success');
    }
     throw(new Error('Username or password incorrect'));
  }
```

If the email is a@gmail.com everything works fine and redux state changes however if login fail, my "catch" operator for some reason doesn't catch the error, instead the error appears in the console as following[image]

In my core module folder I import the module as following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Any one knows what happened here?

Thanks

Comment: Don't throw a `new Error` try just `throw false` or whatever value fits. That should be catched by the catch operator.

Comment: @David Throwing `false` will make no difference. The actual problem is described in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the error in the `login` method is thrown outside of the observable chain composed in your effect.

That is, the error is thrown instead of returning an observable - to which the `map` and `catch` operators would be chained. So it cannot be caught by the `catch`.

Instead, you could return an observable created with `Observable.throw`:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  if (email == 'a@gmail.com') {
    return Observable.of('Login Success');
  }
  return Observable.throw(new Error('Username or password incorrect'));
}
```

Doing so will return an observable that will raise an error notification upon subscription. And that error will be caught by your `catch`.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right and the way I found to solve the problem is to use return ErrorObservable.create(Error('Username or password incorrect')). And then the error is successfully catched~ Thanks!